# Iterative approach to check if a Binary tree is a sum tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

After searching a lot on google, I couldn't find the iterative approach to check whether a Binary search tree is a sum tree.

If anyone has answer, kindly post it here.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the answer on GeeksForGeeks [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-given-binary-tree-is-sumtree/).

```
int isSumTree(struct node* node) 
{ 
    int ls, rs; 

    /* If node is NULL or it's a leaf node then 
       return true */
    if(node == NULL || 
            (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)) 
        return 1; 

   /* Get sum of nodes in left and right subtrees */
   ls = sum(node->left); 
   rs = sum(node->right); 

   /* if the node and both of its children satisfy the 
       property return 1 else 0*/
    if((node->data == ls + rs)&& 
            isSumTree(node->left) && 
            isSumTree(node->right)) 
        return 1; 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21029996)

Comment: Changed it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: this is recursive, OP asked for iterative